# How to change language plugin 'search'?

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

I use Markdown. There is a plugin called search. In this plugin, the search for words in Russian does not work, but the search for English words works. How can I make the search for English and Russian words work in this plugin?

Comment: Which plugin and what program is it a plugin for?

Comment: https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/plugins/#using-plugins — documentation. There is an example of how to add a plugin. I use a standard search plugin, but it only looks for English words.

Answer (score 1):

MkDocs version 0.17 and earlier only support English for search. MkDocs relies on the [lunr.js](http://lunrjs.com/) for search, and by itself, lunr.js only supports English. Therefore, it is currently not possible to support other languages.

However, the search plugin for MkDocs was recently [refactored](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1418) to use [Lunr Languages](https://github.com/MihaiValentin/lunr-languages#lunr-languages-----) (among other changes) and that change will be available in MkDocs version 1.0, which is expected to be released in the next few weeks (I am a member of the development team for MkDocs). A preview of the documentation for the new features can be found [here](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/blob/master/docs/user-guide/configuration.md#search) and is copied below for future reference.

As a reminder, the documentation below **only applies to MkDocs version 1.0**, which has not yet been released.

> **Search**
>
> A search plugin is provided by default with MkDocs which uses
>   [lunr.js](http://lunrjs.com/) as a search engine. The following config options are
>   available to alter the behavior of the search plugin:
>
> ...
>
> **lang**
>
> A list of languages to use when building the search index as
>   identified by their [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) language codes. With [Lunr Languages](https://github.com/MihaiValentin/lunr-languages#lunr-languages-----),
>   the following languages are supported:
>
> - `da`: Danish
> - `du`: Dutch
> - `en`: English
> - `fi`: Finnish
> - `fr`: French
> - `de`: German
> - `hu`: Hungarian
> - `it`: Italian
> - `jp`: Japanese
> - `no`: Norwegian
> - `pt`: Portuguese
> - `ro`: Romanian
> - `ru`: Russian
> - `es`: Spanish
> - `sv`: Swedish
> - `th`: Thai
> - `tr`: Turkish
>
> You may [contribute additional languages](https://github.com/MihaiValentin/lunr-languages/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).
>
> **Warning:**
>
> ```
> While search does support using multiple languages together, it is best not
> to add additional languages unless you really need them. Each additional
> language adds significant bandwidth requirements and uses more browser
> resources. Generally it is best to keep each instance of MkDocs to a single
> language.
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> ```
> Lunr Languages does not currently include support for Chinese or other Asian
> languages. However, some users have reported decent results using Japanese.
> ```
>
> **default**: `['en']`

Comment: OK. I understood. Thanks for the answer.